Identify erotic movie about Lucrezia Borgia
After trying a lot and ending up with no success in finding a movie about Lucrezia Borgia, I followed these guidelines to do the best that I could  generate this question.
I'm looking for a movie about Lucrezia Borgia; this movie I suppose it's R-Rated (but is not a porn like movie, it contains sex, but it also contains...plot).
Descriptions of any characters or locations:
About Lucrecia Borgia; the movie was dubbed into Spanish. I can't remember the name of the actors and actresses but I remember that they're in Italian.
Location: Black castle and interiors of the castle; it was a screen in the stairs of a tower, other in a Bathtub (similar to this one).
Where you watched the movie or TV show:
(When I watched this movie) the channel was called Cinema+ (Colombia), however, I tried to contact (via Twitter) but no answer was received. Now, the channel its called Cinema Plus but again, no results. It was around prior 2007-2010 "I can't remember very well the exact date", but, the movie was transmitted a few time between those years.
Any idea of how old it was:
"I only can suppose" that it's not too old, maybe between 2002-2008.
Any idea of country of origin (if known):
The movie was dubbed to Spanish "Spain", but at the beginning of the movie, it shows the name of the actors and actresses (that was a kind of credits...), I can't remember none of them, but what I do remember is that those names are in Italian.
Whether it was animated or not:
Not animated at all.
Any other distinctive detail:
When I search using the name that I remember: "La princesa de Borgia", the results don't match; in fact, those results are mainly the TV series about The Borgias and a "very old" movie = not the one that I'm looking. Here is the results from imdb website.
I remember that the name pronounced in spanish was "La princesa de Borgia". I tried also search using the keywords principessa borgia but again, no results about the movie that I'm looking for.

You can check the character's history  http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0078627/?ref_=tt_cl_t4

@madmada, I see the link that you provided, but none of them are the movie that I'm looking for, however, the movie that could be close to the movie I'm looking for is Las noches secretas de Lucrecia Borgia (1982) ; but it's very old. Thanks for your help.

Lucrezia Borgia as in [Lucrezia Borgia][1]
[1]: http://assassinscreed.wikia.com/wiki/Lucrezia_Borgia

Thanks Mauricio, I appreciate the effort put into this question. However, do you remember any of the plot? Or any particular scenes at all? What actually happened in this movie?

Hi Mauricio, try and take a look at this list here. The page is in italian but you have posters, images and even some trailers. I guess you can strike out the 1997 (outright porn) and the 2002 (looks like an opera)

@Pesetas74 nice recopilation, I'm looking the link, however none of them looks to the movie that I'm looking for. I'm checking again all the info that all of you have provided me. Thanks.

@Walt, unfortunately, all that I described in my question is all that I can remember.

https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Los_Borgia This is an spain/italian production from 2006, found it on wikipedia, maybe you mean this? I dont speak spain, and there is no english page for it, so i can not read it, maybe you have a look. Also there are 2 Tv-Series about the borgias in 2010, a german one and an english one, did you check both?

Any chance it might have been Lucrezia Donati from the series Da Vincis Demons? The names are the same, the series also depicts Lucrezia to be the daughter of a pope, and there is a similar bathtub scene. However, its English, and I don't think the actors are Italian, still worth a try?

@kl78, no, sorry, that 2006 version isn't the movie that I'm looking for.

@Freya thanks for your comment, but da Vinci's Demons doesn't match with the movie that I'm looking for.

N.B. may classify to NSFW, so please,be careful about open link or even this question in working hours. just an friendly reminder.

After make another search, I found what I think it could be the movie. It's called:

Lucrezia Borgia Le Castellane;

But, each video result is "censored".
Here is the YoutTube link with current time played at a scene in the stairs of a tower that I described in my question. Other scenes kind of match with what I described here.

What I do remember about the tower scene is:

 ...She discover her skirt and reveals that she doesn't have underware,
 the guy make her oral sex and it's interrumped by (what I think she
 is), Lucrecia. The rest of the scence is as is shown in the linked
 YouTube video.

And in the bathtub scene is:

 Lucrecia is taking a shower (I suppose, prepared by the famle who
 appears in the YouTube video) The female "let's called Ana" is
 washing Lucrecia's breasts. (IIRC), both have appasionate kisses and
 more touching continues.

I couldn't find the full movie. This Dailymotion video says:

This device is not supported for premium videos. Please try on a flash
  enabled device.

I tried download it from online convert tools with no avail.

1 Once I see more activity on my question I'll open the bounty, that's because I don't want that these points disappear without anyone gain it.

Locating content is off topic here, that's why edited it out

@AnkitSharma, got it, if I add it as a comment would be considered off-topic too? (just for be sure about whether or not proceed). Thank you

That comments will be removed too

Could it be Immoral Tales

Four historical erotic tales, the last one, is about Lucrezia.
The bathtub featuring on your picture is very similar to the one on
the movie cover 
Some of the actors are italians.
Contains sex.

Otherwise, Castel of Lucrezia.

Sorry, none of the suggestions linked in your answer match with the movie that I watched.
